# Is it possible to install ROS natively for Windows with only VSCode and NOT Visual Studio?

Tags: ros, ros2, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In some professional environments, Visual Studio Community Edition is not allowed and neither are any forms of Ubuntu (whether through WSL/WSL2 or through virtualization). Is it possible to install ROS (1 or 2) natively for Windows 10 with only Visual Studio Code (VSCode) and neither Visual Studio Community nor Visual Studio Pro? None of the setup tutorials hint at this possibility.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372579/is-it-possible-to-install-ros-natively-for-windows-with-only-vscode-and-not-visual-studio?/) by [christopherstelter](https://answers.ros.org/users/70718/christopherstelter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Full Visual Studio installer comes with the build tooling and debuggers, which VSCode leverages. We (Azure Edge Robotics team, who maintains the VSCode ROS extension) have experimented with installing SDKs piecemeal.  I created this tracking bug - https://github.com/ms-iot/vscode-ros/issues/396.

---

Originally posted by [OoeyGUI](https://answers.ros.org/users/37999/ooeygui/) with karma: 186 on 2021-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1